# Interesting results with the '+=' increment operator

Tags: python, increment

I had learned that `n = n + v` and `n += v` are the same. Until this;

```
def assign_value(n, v):
    n += v
    print(n)

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

assign_value(l1, l2)
print(l1)
```

The output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now when I use the expanded version:

```
def assign_value(n, v):
    n = n + v
    print(n)

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

assign_value(l1, l2)
print(l1)
```

The output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Using the `+=` has a different result with the fully expanded operation. What is causing this?

Comment: In python this is because `__add__` and `__iadd__` can be implemented independently and differently.

Comment: *I had learned that n = n + v and n += v are the same.* They are *not* the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem counter-intuitive, but they are not always the same. In fact,

- `a = a + b` means `a = a.__add__(b)`, creating a new object
- `a += b` means `a = a.__iadd__(b)`, mutating the object

[`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__), if absent, defaults to the `__add__`, but it also can (and it does, in the case of lists) mutate the original object in-place.

Answer (score 7):

Thats because in the first implementation you are editing the list n itself (and therefore the changes still apply when leaving the function), while on the other implementation you are creating a new temporary list with the same name, so when you leave the function the new list disappears and the variable n is linked to the original list.

the += operator works similarly to x=x+y for immutable objects (since they always create new objects), but for mutable objects such as lists they work differently. x=x+y creats a new object x while x+=y edits the current object.

Answer (score 1):

This works on how python treats objects and passes variables into functions.
Basically - in first example (with += )
You are passing n and v into function by "pass-by-assignment"
So n gets modified and it will be also modified out of function scope.

In second example - n is reassigned inside of the function to a new list. Which is not seen outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

In your **1st code**. You changes `list n` itself see the below image..!

[image]

In your 2nd code. you just created a temporary list which is cleared when function call ends.. see the below images..!

[image]

In the next step when function ends the temporary list clear!!
[image]